# How does file system on UNIX find files?

Tags: unix, filesystems, kernel

Suppose that a request is made to `ls somefile`. How does the file system in UNIX handle this request from algorithmic perspective? Is that a O(1) query or O(log(N)) depending on files say starting in current directory node, or is it a O(N) linear search, or is that a combination depending on some parameters?

Comment: I've never seen a filesystem that can perform this in O(1).

Comment: Then maybe we should create one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its O(n) since the file systems has to read it off phyical media initially, but Buffer Caches will increase that significantly based on the Virtual File System (VFS) implementation on your flavor of *nix. (Notice how the first time you access a file its slower than the second time you execute the exact same command?)

To learn more read [IBM's article on the Anatomy of the Unix file system](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-filesystem/).

Answer (score 4):

It can be O(n). Classic Unix file systems, based on the old school BSD fast file system and the like,  store files as inode numbers, and their names are assigned at the directory level, not at the file level. This allows you have to the same file present in multiple locations at the same time, via hard links. As such, a "directory" in most Unix systems is just a file that lists filenames and inode numbers for all the files stored "in" that directory.

Searching for a particular filename in a directory just means opening that directory file and parsing through it until you find the filename's entry.

Of course, there's many different file systems available for Unix systems these days, and some will have completely differnet internal semantics for finding files, so there's no one "right" answer.

Comment: What if I want to open the file for reading from some high-language code. Would that first traverse current directory and find the `inode` and then request the file contents?

Comment: On a BSD FFS system, you might have to go through a few layers of directory files before finding the actual file entry you're looking for - a directory entry is limited by the block size of the file system (say, 4k). If you've more filename data than can fit into that 4k block, BSD has to chain extra blocks together to make more space available to store the filenames. There's `opendir()/readdir()/closedir()` and `scandir()` to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: But yes, once you've found the filename's entry in the directory, you've got the inode # representing the file, which is where you actually get the file's contents from. All this is abstracted away behind `fopen()` so you don't have to mess with the low-level nittygritty.

Comment: Would that not make sense to cache directory structure for most frequently accessed directories?

Comment: Everything in Unix is a file (it's the core paradigm of the OS) - so the kernel's own buffers can automatically cache this. If you mean cache this in the client, yes, you can, but remember that Unix is a multi-user OS. You can cache the filename/inode info, but that info may not be valid anymore the next you go looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Typical flow for a program like ls would be

1. Opendir on the current path.
2. Readdir for the current path.
3. Filter the entries returned by the OpenDir through filter provided on the command line. So typically O(n)

This is the generic flow, however there are many optimizations in place for special and frequent cases (;like caching of inode numbers of recent and frequent paths.
Also it depends on how directoy file are organized. In unix it is based on time of creation forcing to read every entry and increasing the look-up time to O(n). In NTFS equivalent of directory files are sorted based on name.

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer your question. Maybe if you take a peak into the source code, you could answer your question yourself and explain us how it works.
[`ls.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c)
[`ls.h`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.h)